# Is the execution of a queued task always guaranteed on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

Is the following simple pattern enough to ensure the task sequence never stops even after application updates or hard, 'erratic' google failures.

```
def do_work():
    ... .... 

    deferred.defer(do_work, _countdown=..in 7 days..)
```

Can I schedule such a self-scheduling worker and never look back?

Answer (score 2):

Two answers:

Yes, tasks will eventually execute and will also retry execution in case of errors in task execution. The retry options are set when you define the task.

No, task queue is not a scheduler, so you can not schedule a task to run at certain time. Tasks put into a task queue are served immediatelly in a FIFO fashion.

As @Jesse noted, for scheduling jobs you should look into GAE cron.

Comment: The `countdown`and `eta` options you can provide are enough to call it 'schedule'.

Comment: @herr.kaste cron is closer to schedule than countdown/eta :)

Answer (score 1):

If a task is queued successfully, it will eventually execute. (And App Engine will keep trying for as long as it takes.)

The pattern you show might be better implemented using [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron), though, which run a task on a regular basis. A common pattern I use is to have a daily cron job kick off a task on a task queue with a small number of retries (so that if there's a temporary glitch, it will retry immediately).

If you do want to use the method above, rather than cron, there's another thing to worry about: since your method can be retried due to it failing or other system issues (e.g. the instance running it going down) you should make sure that you don't end up with two tasks. Imagine if it ran, registered the next task and then the node went down; App Engine would retry, starting a second task. To prevent this, you could use the data store (in a transaction) to test and see if the next task has already been enqueued. Something like:

```
def do_work(counter):
    ...

    @db.transactional
    def start_next():
        # fetch myModel from the data store here
        if myModel.counter == counter:
            return # already started next job
        myModel.counter = counter
        myModel.put()
        deferred.defer(do_work, counter + 1, _transactional=True, _countdown=...)

    start_next()
```

Note the "transactional" argument in the defer call; this ensures that the MyModel instance will be updated if and only if the next task is enqueued.

You might also want to look into sending an email to an administrator after a certain number of failed retries. (You can find this in the request HTTP headers, but you can't use the deferred library if you want to do this; you have to use the task queue API directly.)

Comment: Then: under what circumstances can the self-scheduling deferred.defer call succeed, and the task still fail

Comment: Suppose the instance that the task is running on catches on fire, between the time that the `deferred.defer` call finishes and the time that the do_work function returns.

Comment: remember by naming tasks you will 'in theory' only get one instance in the queue.

Comment: @TimHoffman That's not something you can rely on. [Google's docs on naming tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview#Task_Names) say that while inserting a new task with the same name is supposed to fail, "task names do not provide an absolute guarantee of once-only semantics. In rare cases, multiple calls to create a task of the same name may succeed."

Comment: Note I did say "in theory". Ultimately how good enough this will be will depend on the application and how idempotent the task is.